# how I can store images in firestore and storage multiple

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload multiple images and store them into firebase storage. I can easily select images and post them in the screen, but I can't store them into my firebase storage.

Here is my upload images screen code:

```
const FormModal = () => {


    const [imageUris,setImageUris] = useState([])
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);
    const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
    
 function handleAdd(uri){
        setImageUris([...imageUris,uri])
    }

    const submitForm = async()=>{
        let imgUrl = await uploadImage();
        if(imgUrl == null && userData.userImg){
         imgUrl = userData.userImg
        }
    
                 // Add a new document with a generated id.
            db.collection("imagesFile").add({
                    userId:auth.currentUser?.uid,
                    photo:userData.imgUrl|| null,
                    name: name,
                    phone: phone,
                })
                .then((docRef) => {
                     Alert.alert('Thank You', 'for your donation.')
                    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
                });
            }

 {/*upload Image to firebase sotrage*/}
    const uploadImage = async ()=>{
            if(image == null){
              return "";
            }
            const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
              const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
              xhr.onload = function (){
                 resolve(xhr.response)
              };
              xhr.onerror = function (){
                  reject( new TypeError("Network request failed"))
        
              };
              xhr.responseType = "blob"
              xhr.open("GET",image,true)
              xhr.send(null)
            });
            const ref = firebase.storage().ref().child("images/" + new Date().toISOString())
            const snapshot = ref.put(blob)
        
            snapshot.on(
              firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
              ()=>{
                  setUploading(true)
              },
              (error)=>{
                  setUploading(false)
                  console.log(error)
                  blob.close();
                  return ;
              },
              ()=>{
                  snapshot.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((url)=>{
                    
                    setUserData({...userData, imgUrl: url})
                    setUploading(false);
                     // Alert.alert('Profile Updated', 'You profile Updated Successfully..!')
                      console.log('donwload:', url)
                      blob.close()
                      return null
                  })
              }
            )
         
           }

     return(
    {/*the form details*/}
          <ScrollView
          style={{
            marginTop:SIZES.padding,
            paddingHorizontal:SIZES.padding,
            bottom:SIZES.padding2
          }}
        >
            {/*Add Image*/}
            <View
              style={{
                height:100
              }}
            >
                 <FormImageInput 
                     imageUris={imageUris}
                     onAddImage={handleAdd}
                     onRemoveImage={handleRemove}
                 />
            </View>
                {/*Donator Name*/}
            <FormInput
                label='Donator Name:'
                value={name}
                />
                
                {/*Donatore Phone*/}
            <FormInput
                label='Phone:'
                keyboardType='number-pad'
                value={phone}
               
                />
                <AppButton
                    label='Upload'
                    onPress={()=>
                        submitForm()
                       
                    }
   )
```

FormImageInput code

```
const FormImageInput=({imageUris=[], onRemoveImage, onAddImage})=>{

    return(
        <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>

            {imageUris.map(uri =>
            (
                <View
                  key={uri}
                  style={{
                    marginRight:SIZES.base
                  }}
                >
                    <ImageInput imageUri={uri} onChangeImage={()=>onRemoveImage(uri)}/> 
                </View>
  
            ))}
            <ImageInput  onChangeImage={uri=>onAddImage(uri)} />
        </View>
    )
}
```

Select Image screen code

```
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';

const ImageInput=({imageUri, onChangeImage})=>{

    
    useEffect(()=>{
        requestPermission()
    },[])



    const requestPermission = async()=>{
        const {granted} = await ImagePicker.requestCameraPermissionsAsync()
        if(!granted) alert('You need to enable permission to access the labirary')

    }


    function handlePress(){
        if (!imageUri) selectImage()
        else Alert.alert('Delete', 'Are you sure you want to delete this image?',[
            {text:'Yes', onPress:()=>onChangeImage(null)},
            {text:'No'}
        ])
    }


   const selectImage = async()=>{
    try {
        const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
            allowsEditing: true,
            quality: 0.5,
        })
        if(!result.canceled) onChangeImage(result.assets[0].uri)
    } catch (error) {
          console.log("Error")
    }
   }

    return(
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={handlePress}>
        <View
           style={style.container}
        >
            {!imageUri && (<Image source={icons.camera}
              resizeMode='contain'
              style={{
                height:80,
                width:80,
                borderRadius:SIZES.radius
              }}
            />)}
            {imageUri && <Image source={{uri:imageUri}} 
              style={{
                height:80,
                width:80,
                borderRadius:SIZES.radius
            }}/>}
        </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    )
}
```

so I put Image picker in different component and then I called in Form Image Input screen to keep after that I called the Image Input compoement to my Upload Image screen to choose and select more than one image but I can't store images but I can display them any idea please.

Comment: The code syntax in your question is invalid. Please [edit] it to be correct and preferably, formatted for readability. I recommend running it through Prettier before posting